# Subtract two columns with NAs across multiple columns

Tags: r

I wish to subtract every successive column with values from the preceding column.

List

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   2   3   4   6
2   2   2   3   NA
3   4   5   NA  NA
1   NA  NA  2   4
```

Result

```
1   1   1   2
0   0   1   NA
1   1   NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  2
```

I can do it by column binding all results `as.matrix((ifelse(!is.na(List[,1])&!is.na(List[,2], List[,2]-List[,1], "NA")))` across the columns but that seems awfully tedious.

1. Is there a faster way?
2. In the case of the last lane in `List`, how could I obtain the value of the difference between two values (Column D - Column A) divided by the intervals between them (3 intervals)? So instead of `Result`, we have:

Alt_result

```
1   1   1   2
0   0   1   NA
1   1   NA  NA
NA  NA  0.333  2
```

Comment: What do you mean by the `last lane`?

Comment: The last line of `List`, we have c(1,NA,NA,2,4). In point 2, would it be possible to modify the code such that it divides the difference between the 2 columns by the distance between two non-NA values?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me.  Why you are changing only a single cell i.e. with 0.33?

Comment: My apologies. In that sole case, 2 (in the 4th column) is separated by 2 NAs from 1 (in the 1st column) - so there're 3 intervals between them (1st: 1 and NA; 2nd: NA and NA; 3rd: NA and 2). So, (2-1)/3 = 0.333 Ideally it would be nice to factor in the number of intervals in obtaining the difference between two non-NA numbers as it would increase the number of valid observations in the dataset. Of course in the data, there are many such cases.

Answer (score 2):

We subset the dataset by removing the last column `[-ncol(d1)]` and first one `[-1]` and subtract those equally sized datasets so that each column will be subtracted by the preceding ones.

```
abs(d1[-ncol(d1)]- d1[-1])
#   A  B  C  D
#1  1  1  1  2
#2  0  0  1 NA
#3  1  1 NA NA
#4 NA NA NA  2
```

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done by applying the `diff` function row wise

```
t(apply(df,1,diff))
#      B  C  D  E
#[1,]  1  1  1  2
#[2,]  0  0  1 NA
#[3,]  1  1 NA NA
#[4,] NA NA NA  2
```